# Pulling / saving a few docker images in parallel - failure

Tags: docker, docker-pull, overlayfs

I am trying to pull and save a few docker images in parallel (they are quite big and parallelism can save a lot of time - it is done within a Python script activating docker pull and then save within each thread). However, it fails all the time with the message like this:

Client Error: Not Found ("open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/41693d132695cd5ada8cf37f210d5b70bc1bac1b2cedfa5a4f352efa5ff00fc6/merged/some_file_name: no such file or directory")

the specific file on which it complains ('no such file or directory') varies.
In /var/log/messages (even after adding the debug flag to docker daemon options) I can't see anything valuable.
e.g.

level=error msg="Handler for GET /v1.35/images/xxx/xxx:xxx/get returned error: open /var/lib/docker/overlay2/41693d132695cd5ada8cf37f210d5b70bc1bac1b2cedfa5a4f352efa5ff00fc6/merged/opt/external/postgresql-42.2.5/postgresql-42.2.5.ja
r: no such file or directory"

Important (probably) note: - the images share many layers in common as they are built based on the same parent images (is this the reason for the collision in overlay FS?).
Running the same sequentually (number of parallel threads set to 1) works perfectly

OS: centos 7.9
Docker:
Server Version: 1.13.1
Storage Driver: overlay2
Backing Filesystem: xfs

Comment: What do you mean by save? Pulling should take care of storing the layers.

Comment: 'save' means docker save (saving the image into a tar file)

Comment: did you check this out: https://github.com/docker/for-linux/issues/478 seems like a prun or a restart helpd to recover for some people. Does it work when doing it sequential

Comment: The problem is that most of the discussions about the subject (at least those I found and I searched as much as I could) get focused about the "next step", meaning what to do after such a failure occurs. For me docker system prune -a fixes the local repository, however I must find a solution which prevents the described issue and lets me pull and save images in parallel (currently sequential job pulling the images from external repo and saving them into local tar files takes around 10h due to the big sizes and high number of images).